# MySQL ifnull sub query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table and set a column, `set_price`, if it is `null` to a value from another table.

Both records share the same `prod_id`. Can someone look over my query and tell me whats wrong with it?

```
 update list_items l 
 set purchased = "YES", 
 set_price =  IFNULL(set_price,(select pricelast 
                     from inventory i where i.prod_id=l.prod_id)) 
 where l.list_id=1
```

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Please post the specific error  - this query can be expressed with a JOIN using MySQL's [multi-table update syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Comment: set_price is column name.

No error message, simply Affected rows: 0 (Query took 0.0017 sec)

select pricelast   from inventory i where i.prod_id= 2 gives 2.00 as result.

Comment: well, are there entries with `prod_id = 2` and `list_id = 1` in the `list_items`?

Comment: this part of your subquery: `from inventory i where i.prod_id=l.prod_id` I don't think the subquery knows about `l.prod_id`. But I would think you would get an error for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way would be using join update with the use of case-when something as

```
update list_items l 
left join inventory i on i.prod_id=l.prod_id
set l.purchased = 'YES',
l.set_price = 
case 
  when l.set_price is null then i.pricelast else l.set_price
end
```

Comment: Thaks that worked great. I just had to add a where list_id = part at the end.

Comment: Ah sorry I missed that.